# PDE self study background required

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have just finished reading an undergraduate level book on ODEs in my spare time and now would like to read on PDEs. After going through these forums, I have picked up John Fritz's book as my first PDE book.

I would like to ask what background is required to be able to get the most out of this book and be able to learn at least 3/4th of the concepts presented.

My final goal is to understand the book by Evans on PDEs.

Comment: What difficulties amongst the material have led you to ask this? Just give it a shot, and do your best. Books don't bite (except Rudin)

Comment: @DonLarynx I asked this question wondering whether the background that helped me understand ODEs is also enough for PDEs. Or do I need to read some preparatory material/book.

Comment: Yes, basically the PDE book itself.

Comment: Thats very encouraging to know! Would you say the same thing for the book by Evans on PDEs? It is supposed to be a graduate level text.

Comment: If you've had your basic course in measure theory and $L^p$ spaces, you shouldn't need anything more to read Evans. From what I remember of John, a good understanding of advanced calculus (i.e. a first course in analysis) is probably sufficient to read through.

Answer (score 3):

I have finished reading PDE course of Engineering . It requires only basic concept of calculas . Nothing else .Read the materials carefully . Hope you will get the concept of PDE .